# Show more and show less of textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Please click: `click it` and then: by adding some lines into the function: `Show_More_Less()`, can someone tell me please how can I do the next following:

1) if the user presses "show more" - all the text is showed and the `show more` will become `show less'.

2) "show less" - 90 characters of the text are showed and the `show less` will become `show more`.

I tried to do that but I override the text (and that's why it is changed to 90 characters forever).

**I want the initial condition will be: shows only 90 characters and the text of the div will be `show more`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

function add_text_to_textarea() {
   var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore";

    if (str.length > 90) {
         document.getElementById('show_more_less').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else {
         document.getElementById('show_more_less').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str;

}

function Show_More_Less() {
    var e = document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML.toUpperCase();
    var str = document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML;
    if (e == "SHOW MORE") {
        document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str;
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML = "Show less";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str.substr(0,90);
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML = "Show more";
    }
 }
</script>

<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<div id="run_fun" onClick="add_text_to_textarea();">click it</div>
<div id="show_more_less" onClick="Show_More_Less();" style="visibility : hidden;">Show more</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I've noticed you don't use `jQuery` at all and this makes your question extremely hard, - I doubt there are people who even remember how to spell "getElementById". Using `jQuery` on the other hand would make this question robust, understood, good to read, and it would save your time you've spent for writing this question, because `jQuery` lets you write less and do more. You could've spent this time to do vacuum-cleaning or to do your dishes or go to a concert. After all, you could save my time too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `var str` as a global variable accessible by both function. The instead of changing the `str` on every click with `.innerHTML`, just do the substring on the global variable without changing it :

```
var str = '';
function add_text_to_textarea() {
    str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore";

    if (str.length > 90) {
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str.substr(0,90);
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML = "Show more";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str;
    }

}

function Show_More_Less() {
    var e = document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML.toUpperCase();
    if (e == "SHOW MORE") {
        document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str;
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML = "Show less";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str.substr(0,90);
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML = "Show more";
    }
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wY9rY/1/

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work.. I want the initial condition will be: showing 90 characters and there is `show more`.

Comment: Edited my answer, change the ` add_text_to_textarea` function and the fiddle. But honnestly, you could have figured that one since I just copied your show more function!

Answer (score 2):

Add a global variable that'll hold the content of the string before you trim it - and when needed - recover the information from that variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

function add_text_to_textarea() {
   var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore";

    if (str.length > 90) {
         document.getElementById('show_more_less').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else {
         document.getElementById('show_more_less').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str;

}
string_saver = "";

function Show_More_Less() {
    var e = document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML.toUpperCase();
    var str = document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML;  
    if (e == "SHOW MORE") {
        if(string_saver != "") str = string_saver;
        document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str;
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML = "Show less";
    }
    else {
        string_saver = str;
        document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = str.substr(0,90);
        document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML = "Show more";
    }
 }
</script>

<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<div id="run_fun" onClick="add_text_to_textarea();">click it</div>
<div id="show_more_less" onClick="Show_More_Less();" style="visibility : hidden;">Show less</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Link to **[fidder](http://jsfiddle.net/wY9rY/4/)**

Comment: thank you, but I want the initial condition will be: showing 90 characters and there is `show more` "button"..

Comment: @AlonShmiel that's an easy fix - check-out the new code/fiddle